# Amazon AWS Lightsail + Cloudflare - Nameserver update?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, amazon-route53, denial-of-service

I have a DNS zone set up in AWS Lightsail and have the static nameservers displayed in Lightsails DNS Zone menu. The domain was bought via Amazon's Route 53 where I have another DNZ Zone with the same domain including various CNAME, A, etc records.

Now, I want to add Cloudflare to my Lightsail server and have consequently changed the Route 53 nameservers to point to Cloudflare, which then should redirect to the Lightsail name servers. The problem now is that its been 36 hours and nothing happened. I did some research and learned that Lightsail runs pretty autonomously from the rest of AWS and doesnt need Route 53 configuration, but on the other hand does not allow for me to change any NS records inside the Lightsail DNS Zone settings.

So long story short: how does one go to add Cloudflare to an AWS Instance hosted on Lightsail, with a domain bought via Route 53?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

:|

You pretty much want to stick to one NS provider.

If you want to use cloudflare features, then you configure CF nameservers in Route53.

On the CF side , when your site 'foo.com' has been confirmed to be onboarded, you will add a DNS A & optionally a WWW record pointing to the public ip of your 'foo.com' site/instance.

You don't configure Lightsail DNS NS on CF, but the public IP of your instance where you'll be serving 'foo.com'